# How to list all tables and their creators (or owners) in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I thought it is straightforward but I couldn't find a way to list all tables and their creators (or owners) in Redshift. Any help/insight is welcome.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It was pg_tables table and here is the SQL:

```
select tablename, tableowner From pg_tables
```

Answer (score 23):

You can list Redshift tables, views and their owners by running this script:

```
SELECT n.nspname AS schema_name
 , pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) AS table_owner
 , c.relname AS table_name
 , CASE WHEN c.relkind = 'v' THEN 'view' ELSE 'table' END 
   AS table_type
 , d.description AS table_description
 FROM pg_class As c
 LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
 LEFT JOIN pg_tablespace t ON t.oid = c.reltablespace
 LEFT JOIN pg_description As d 
      ON (d.objoid = c.oid AND d.objsubid = 0)
 WHERE c.relkind IN('r', 'v') 
ORDER BY n.nspname, c.relname ;
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. Doesn't even show any tables in the public schema.

Comment: @Appleoddity  : works for me. Maybe you do not have sufficient permissions